# Harness Shard customization

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

An 8th-level Aegis has 14 power points (due to level, race and other stuff), so if he customizes his suit with harness shard, he can create 14 shards. This round, he uses them all trying to hit one foe.

How much damage does each one do? What's the range? 1d3/1d4 and 6 mt as standard shard?

And next round, he can use all of them again; they don't disintegrate, right? So each round, he can add 14d3/4 to his normal attack. Correct?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Harness shard* allows you to use a [*shard*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/universal-items#TOC-Shards), a type of consumable psionic item, without that *shard* disintegrating as it normally would. *Shards* give competence bonuses to a single skill: they cannot be used to attack at all, or to improve normal attacks. They only improve skills, and the skill is chosen by whoever created the *shard*, as is the amount of bonus offered by the *shard*.

So *harness shard* just lets you re-use a *shard* instead of it just being a one-use item.